# Network drive wont appear or allow anyone to use it

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that has a drive in it called X: that I would like to use as a drive that everyone can access. However, I can't seem to get it to appear on anyone's computer.

I can access it when I am signed in as the domain administrator at \servername\x$ but when I am signed in as a non-administrator I cannot access it. I have tried to set it to map in group policy but no luck, nor does drive-sharing do anything.

How do I get this drive to appear on all user's computers, so everyone can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is actually in

[Windows Server 2008 R2 mapped shares do not show up in command line](https://serverfault.com/questions/408409/windows-server-2008-r2-mapped-shares-do-not-show-up-in-command-line)

which was asking about why a mapped drive was not available in an elevated command prompt.  The answer pointed at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143(v=vs.85).aspx  and quotes it as follows:

> Drive letters are not global to the system. Each logon session receives its own set of drive letters from A to Z. Therefore, redirected drives cannot be shared between processes running under different user accounts. Moreover, a service (or any process running within its own logon session) cannot access the drive letters that were established within a different logon session.